# Cannot find equivalent of system.web.compilation.tempDirectory for system.webServer

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

In `web.config`, what is the equivalent of `system.web`>`compilation[tempDirectory]` attribute but using the more up to date `system.webServer` instead of `system.web`?

Here is what I need to add to my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="W:\vhosts\mysite.com\tmp" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, my current `web.config` relies on `system.webServer`, not `system.web` and adding the attribute results in an internal server error 500.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compilation[tempDirectory]` is depending on `system.web`, so you cannot add it in `system.webServer`.

But `system.web` and `system.webServer` can both exist in web.config. They won't lead to conflict.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

 <system.web>
<compilation tempDirectory="W:\vhosts\mysite.com\tmp" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked! In a nutshell "The system.web section isn't superseded by the system.webserver section, just extended"